# random custom field wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I have 3 custom fields on a page, they are dailytip_1, dailytip_2 and dailytip_3.

So I want to show only 1 tip of the 3 tips randomly on the page. What I can do? Thanks!

```
<?php $dailytip_1 = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'dailytip_1', true); ?>

<?php if ($dailytip_1 !== '') { ?>
    <p><?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'dailytip_1', true); ?></p>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Do you know how to get a custom field from WordPress? Or do you need all the code?

Comment: I know a little bit. If you can show me a complete one that'd great! thank you! Have updated the question that's all I know.

Comment: Hi Jason, could you help on that please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the following help?

```
<?php
    $random_dailytip = 'dailytip_' . rand( 0, 2 );
    $dailytip = get_post_meta($post->ID, $random_dailytip, true);

?>

<?php if ($dailytip !== '') { ?>
    <p><?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, $random_dailytip, true); ?></p>
<?php } ?>
```

As you can see, `$random_dailytip` gets the values `dailytip_0`, `dailytip_1` or `dailytip_2` randomly.

Comment: That works. Actually i have 5 tips and the array, then it should be rand(0,4). shouldn't it? Thanks Alan.

Comment: Yes, it should be `rand( 0, 4 )` in that case. You are welcome.

Comment: I'm keep refreshing the page. It seems that it doesn't get any content sometime. And I'm sure I put all the values for all the 5 tips, anyidea?

Comment: I see it begins from dailytip_0 Have changed it to rand( 1, 5 ). Should be good now. right?

Comment: Well, if you want a range of 1 to 5, you can use `rand( 1, 5 )`.

Comment: Nice to know that. Then, try considering accepting my answer.